# How to add a dependency to a systemd.mount that is activated by /bin/mount?

Tags: linux, mount, systemd

I want systemd on `mount /mnt/test` to automatically call a program (in real life `cryptsetup` to unlock the underlying device, for testing here `echo`) before the file system is mounted and after it is unmounted.

With `/etc/systemd/system/stickbak-encryption.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=stickbak encryption
Before=mnt-test.mount
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo Unlock device.
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/echo Lock device.

[Install]
RequiredBy=mnt-test.mount
```

and `/etc/fstab` (partly):

```
/dev/$DEVICE /mnt/test auto noauto 0 0
```

this works (after daemon reload and enabling the service) for `systemctl start mnt-test.mount` and respectively `systemctl stop mnt-test.mount` (as root).

On `mount /mnt/test`, however, `systemctl status mnt-test.mount stickbak-encryption` shows the latter service being `inactive (dead)`, while the former is `active (mounted)`.

How can I (or can I not?) set up a dependency that is honoured when `/bin/mount` is called as well?  The status of the mount unit shows that `mount /mnt/test` seems to be translated to `ExecMount=/bin/mount /dev/$DEVICE /mnt/test -t auto -o noauto`, so apparently systemd gets notified.

Comment: since fstab is automatically parsed by systemd, and given that a quick google search resulted in no input on how one could control the generated mount file in a way to specify dependencies, I would guess this is impossible at this moment, but I really hope to be wrong and to see someone answer this question positively, for I'd profit out of it as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I very recently asked myself the same question, but I quickly came to the realisation that it doesn't work that way.

When you use the `mount` command-line program, systemd is not involved: `mount` reads `/etc/fstab` (or takes options from the command-line) and mounts the device. When you start a systemd mount unit, it's parsed by systemd which internally uses mount system calls to perform the mount.

So there is no way to systemd to get involved when you use `mount`.

As an aside, there is an interesting difference between using `mount` and systemd in what they accept as valid in `/etc/fstab`. Systemd parses the file and creates mount units that it then uses. When it does so, it accepts fewer parameters than `mount` requires.

If you use systemd then you only have to supply the device and mount point, however `mount` requires further options such as the file system and options.